# Possible to have a Infopath form generate multiple, uniquely assigned, copies of itself and post to sharepoint list/library?

Tags: infopath

We are currently using a sharepoint page in conjunction with an Infopath form. We create a new form using the + button and fill it out and submit a separate form for each division it belongs to (same form, same info etc just different division name)

Is it possible to have the form generate an identical form for each division (possibly selected from a list) and have it be its own unique form rather than having to fill out each form individually with the same information over and over again?

We have been able to assign multiple divisions to one form, but not have the form create a unique form for each division so they can sign off on them and have them complete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not recommended to develop any new form using infopath as infopath is deprecated, after 2022 there won't be any support for infopath form from Microsoft, so it's not recommended to go with infopath form... As far as the modern SharePoint form is concerned, the current trend and future is Powerapps with MS Flow.

Coming to the question, let's take we are going with this infopath form approach, as I understand you are dealing with various department data... then I think we should not think about creating multiple forms rather we can create multiple views for various departments and based on the department we can send data to respective departments library either using submit rules or vsto coding.

And if we implement the the same thing using list form, we can create multiple content type which will have department specific columns based on the division or department... then we can control these data from the single list through the department specific view. Or if at all want to move the department specific data to the different specific location, we can write a workflow on item creation then based on the content type we can push the data to the division specific target list/library.